# C# TagLib raise 0xc00d36c4 after add Album Image From Url

Tags: c#, taglib

I try to add album image to my mp3 audio file use `TagLib`.

but if I open mp3 file after adding album art, the player raises the error 0xc00d36c4.

this is the code I tried...

```
var wReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(procItem.Thumbnail);
var wRes = (HttpWebResponse)wReq.GetResponse();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (Stream s = wRes.GetResponseStream())
    {
        int data;
        while ((data = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, data);
        }
    }

    TagLib.File tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(procItem.DownloadDirectory);
    IPicture newArt = new Picture(ms.ToArray());
    tagFile.Tag.Pictures = new IPicture[1] { newArt };
    tagFile.Save();
}
```

one of interesting thing is if I load an mp3 file info in my program, the image control draw album art.

It just raised when mp3 file open.

> procitem.Thumbnail is the album image Url

Comment: Have you tried to google the errorcode? It may be worth trying ...

Comment: @Fildor I think the mp3 file is broken by taglib work.

Comment: When I did a quick google, there were also a lot of "How to fix ..." references. Maybe try to check some them out. Maybe it's not about your code at all? You should add to your question if you have tried something and failed. Otherwise it will be suggested to you unnecessarily.

Comment: @Fildor why i did not searching from google? because the error be happend after program works end. if you think I'm so lazy or not trying-man, Im sorry Im not good at english and english grammer so I can't express well for you what I did.

Comment: I didn't accuse you of anything. I am trying to help you improve the question, so you can get better answers. Bad english will be tolerated and probably improved by someone. Bad questions will be closed.

Comment: @Fildor K, I got that, Thx

Comment: No idea if this could help, but I found this snippet in one of my old prjects: `if (musicFile.Tag.Pictures.Length >= 1)
{
    var bin = (byte[])(musicFile.Tag.Pictures[0].Data.Data);
    TD.cover = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bin)).GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, IntPtr.Zero);
}` ((Maybe the player is missing the `cover` thumbnail?))